# select * from (select a,b,c ...) guaranteed order of result columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, relational-database, relation

I recently had a comment in a code review:

> it's better to enumerate the fields explicitly. "select *" doesn't
>   guarantee an order

Is that true in this case with a query like `select * from (select a,b,c ...)`? I can't imagine a database engine that would re-order the columns in the result, but then my imagination is more logical than some database engines.

Comment: Why take the chance? (Also, ideally, whatever is consuming the results of the query should be accessing the columns by *name* and not *position* so the alternative question is "does it matter?")

Comment: On the other hand, your application should not depend on a certain order of the columns returned, because then what happens when someone changes the query? The reason to eschew `SELECT *` is not based on the order in which the columns are returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice against `select *` is mainly for when you're querying tables directly.

In some databases it's possible to insert a new column partway through a table, such that table `t (a, b)` becomes table `t (a, c, b)`. PostgreSQL does not (yet) support this, but it can still append columns, and it can drop columns from anywhere, so you can still get `t (a, c)` if you add `c` and drop `b`.

This is why it's considered bad practice to use `*` in production queries, especially if your application relies on ordinal column position to read results. But really, that only applies to situations where you do not specify the fields elsewhere in the query.

In your case you do so in the subquery. So `*` is perfectly safe and IMO quite acceptable in this usage.

This:

```
select * from (select a,b,c ... from t)
```

is fine.

This:

```
select * from t
```

or

```
select * from (select * from t)
```

are problematic, because they leave the column-order undefined to the application. Even then that's only a problem if your application *assumes* the column order without checking the query metadata.

Personally I prefer to fully qualify my columns most of the time, but there sure are times when `*` is the most readable option.

It's also, IMO, quite fine to use `select *` when the client application reads columns by name, not by ordinal. If your app never cares if `c` is the 2nd column or the 3rd because it uses the result metadata to build a row dictionary (like Perl's DBI or Python's psycopg2 can do) then there's no real reason not to just use `*`.

There can be performance costs to `SELECT *` when you only need a subset of columns, though. Missed opportunities to use index-only scans, unnecessary fetching of out-of-line TOASTed data, and bandwidth wasted for unwanted values, among other things. So most of the time it's still not a great idea.

Comment: I'd only use `select *` if the query has, in some other way, already reduced the columns down to those that are required (such as in the OPs question, via a subquery that doesn't use `select *`). Otherwise you're still vulnerable to the other downside of `select *` - forcing the database to retrieve more data (once new columns are added) that the consumer will never make use of.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point - it can make s huge difference too. Might prevent an index-only scan ftom being used for example. Or force useless fetches from TOAST out-of-line storage. Not to mention possible bandwidth impact. In this user's case the column set is already constrained though.

Answer (score 1):

The columns are always in the order defined in the table. However the rows aren't always fetched in the same order if no order by clause is included.

Comment: In this case where the "table" is the inner select, the columns should be in order right?